# PDO INSERT not working with $_POST Variables

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm pulling my hair out over this- hopefully it's an easy oversight.

I'm planning on sending a bunch of variables to this PHP files with a jQuery AJAX function. I wrote this section to assign all $_POST variables to php variables:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

and it seems to be working, because I can manipulate the variables like so:

```
echo 'name: ' . $name . '<br>';
echo 'main_pic: ' . $main_pic . '<br>';
echo 'product_pic: ' . $product_pic . '<br>';
echo 'more_pic: ' . $more_pic . '<br>';
echo 'paypal_code: ' . $paypal_code . '<br>';
echo 'category_id: ' . $category_id . '<br>';
echo 'price: ' . $price . '<br>';
echo 'description: ' . $description . '<br>';
echo 'product_color: ' . $product_color . '<br>';
echo 'design_color: ' . $design_color;
```

So now that I have those, I want to insert them into my table-

```
$qry = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO inventory (name, main_pic, product_pic, more_pic, paypal_code, category_id, price, description, product_color, design_color) 
                                            VALUES (:name, :main_pic, :product_pic, :more_pic, :paypal_code, :category_id, :price, :description, :product_color, :design_color)");

    $qry-> bindParam(':name', $name);
    $qry-> bindParam(':main_pic', $main_pic);
    $qry-> bindParam(':product_pic', $product_pic);
    $qry-> bindParam(':more_pic', $more_pic);
    $qry-> bindParam(':paypal_code', $paypal_code);
    $qry-> bindParam(':category_id', $category_id);
    $qry-> bindParam(':price', $price);
    $qry-> bindParam(':description', $description);
    $qry-> bindParam(':product_color', $product_color);
    $qry-> bindParam(':design_color', $design_color);
    $qry-> execute();
```

This doesn't run- and I'm not sure the best way to log an error to see why. If I manually assign the variables and comment out my earlier $_POST shenanigans, everything seems to work and the INSERT runs fine.

Any clues? I thought it might be because the database is expecting certain variable type, but I think I've fully explored that.

Anyone know of any reasons that manually assigning the variables would work but grabbing them from $_POST wouldn't?

EDIT: following those suggestions, I've got an error message
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Alright, so I'm not assigning a unique Primary key when I'm trying this insert- I was under the assumption that PDO would handle that. What is the best way to handle assigning a unique Primary key? I'd like to avoid having the user manually assign it.

Comment: Enable `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` to see if it finds any wrongdoing on your part.

Comment: If you were to put the URL you are querying with AJAX into a browser, it should (if you've set for all errors to display) show you what's gone wrong. Alternatively you may have an error_log file in the root of your web folder. Any information from these would help.

Comment: Enabled error codes and edited the question with more information. Thanks!

Comment: Is your `prepare`/`execute` done in the same function as the "POST shenanigans"? What is your table structure (`DESCRIBE inventory`)?

Comment: Accepted an answer, but there's a nice little discussion below on why what I'm doing above is a coding horror. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty your database table and see if it works... Likely you have a primary key in your db table that you are trying to overwrite.

Check your db table as well, using `EXPLAIN inventory`

Comment: Turns out that's exactly what it is- now I've just got to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but it will look better than a comment. Why are you doing the following:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

This is register globals all over again (sort of). With above code you can easily overwrite local variables with unexpected results or even worse introduce security vulnerabilities.

What if I post `$_POST['is_admin'] = 1` or something like that? Either way I think you get the idea. What you just did is bad and can be dangerous.

Comment: Would this be solved by namespacing the variables, or should I avoid doing something like this entirely? I'd like to be able to add new fields to my form and minimize any code changes.

Comment: @ThomasPatrickHorton You'd be best to create a white-list key array, and iterate through it for binding. *That* would help minimize code changes, and avoid this register globals catastrophe waiting to happen.

Comment: @ThomasPatrickHorton if you add fields you will have to change code either way, because otherwise your query wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah- this is exactly why they say not to roll your own code. This is really just an exploratory project- I understand that there's a lot of vulnerabilities to navigate. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Like @PeeHaa, this is not an answer, but to expand on my comment on his; drop the pseudo register globals functionality: opt for a white-list of fields, and coordinate the names with those posted.

```
$fields = ['name', 'age', 'sex'];

$query = $pdo->prepare(sprintf('INSERT INTO `table` (%s) VALUES (%s)', 
    implode(',', $fields), 
    implode(',', array_map(function($field) {
        return ":{$field}";
    }, $fields))));

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $query->bind(":{$field}", $_POST[$field]);
}

$query->execute();
```

Obviously, this needs more validation, empty() checking, etc., but you get the idea. Furthermore, you can add more validation/sanitization with a callback lookup:

```
$sanitizers = [
    'sex' => function($value) {
        $value = strtolower($value);
        return in_array($value, ['male', 'female', 'unknown']) 
            ? $value : 'unknown';
    },
];

foreach($sanitizers as $field => $sanitizer) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $_POST[$field] = $sanitizer($_POST[$field]);
    }
}
```

If post contains "genderless" for "sex", you'll get "unknown" instead.

---

More complete example:

```
// whitelist keys and sanitizer values
$fields = [
    // limit to 255 
    'name' => function($value) {
        return substr($value, 0, 255);
    }, 
    // you can't be that old
    'age' => function($value) {
        return min(max((int) $value, 0), 100);
    },
    // starfish need not apply
    'sex' => function($value) {
        $value = strtolower($value);
        return in_array($value, ['male', 'female', 'unknown']) 
            ? $value : 'unknown';
    },
];

// build ye' old query
$query = $pdo->prepare(sprintf('INSERT INTO `table` (%s) VALUES (%s)', 
    implode(',', array_keys($fields)), 
    implode(',', array_map(function($fields){
        return ":${$field}";
    }, array_keys($fields)))));

// loop dee doop to sanitize and bind
foreach ($fields as $key => $sanitizer) {
    if (is_callable($sanitizer)) {
        $query->bind(":{$field}", $sanitizer($_POST[$field]));
        continue;
    }
    $query->bind(":{$field}", $_POST[$field]);
}

// fire the cannons!
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Very helpful- this is a great start.

Comment: @ThomasPatrickHorton No prob Bob; I updated with a more complete version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can have an autoincremented primary key. Supposing you use mysql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

> **The OP said:** 
>   Alright, so I'm not assigning a unique Primary key when I'm trying
>   this insert- I was under the assumption that PDO would handle that.
>   What is the best way to handle assigning a unique Primary key? I'd
>   like to avoid having the user manually assign it.

Just addressing this part or your question - you just use an unquoted 0

```
insert into table (id, name) values (0, 'Bob');
```

But as you say, you should not have to if it is an id which is auto-incrementing correctly.

In old versions of Mysql (< 5) you could use an empty string, which blew up when 5.0 came out, just in case anyone reading this fell foul of that previously undocumented feature.